# Rainfall Challenge (August 2016 Community Challenge)

Tags: c#, community-challenge

My solution for the [Rainfall Challenge (August 2016 Community Challenge)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6911/104803).

Error handling was intentionally ignored.

---

### Cell.cs

```
public class Cell
{
    private readonly int myRowIndex;
    private readonly int myColIndex;
    private readonly int myValue;

    public Cell(int value, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
    {
        myRowIndex = rowIndex;
        myColIndex = colIndex;
        myValue = value;
    }

    public int RowIndex => myRowIndex;
    public int ColIndex => myColIndex;
    public int Value => myValue;
    public bool IsSink { get; set; }
    public Cell Top { get; set; }
    public Cell Right { get; set; }
    public Cell Bottom { get; set; }
    public Cell Left { get; set; }
    public Cell Next { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Program.cs

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = ReadData();

    var cells = CreateCells(data).ToArray();

    ConnectCells(cells, data.GetLength(0));

    SetIsSink(cells);

    SetNext(cells);

    var basins = GetBasins(cells);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", basins));
}
```

**ReadData**

```
private static int[,] ReadData()
{
    var size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var result = new int[size, size];
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        var rowData = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
            result[row, col] = int.Parse(rowData[col]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**CreateCells**

```
private static IEnumerable<Cell> CreateCells(int[,] data)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < data.GetLength(0); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); col++)
            yield return new Cell(data[row, col], row, col);
}
```

**ConnectCells**

```
private static void ConnectCells(Cell[] cells, int size)
{
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        var indexLeft = GetIndexLeft(cell, size);
        var indexRight = GetIndexRight(cell, size);
        var indexTop = GetIndexTop(cell, size);
        var indexBottom = GetIndexBottom(cell, size);

        if (indexLeft > -1) cell.Left = cells[indexLeft];
        if (indexRight > -1) cell.Right = cells[indexRight];
        if (indexTop > -1) cell.Top = cells[indexTop];
        if (indexBottom > -1) cell.Bottom = cells[indexBottom];
    }
}

private static int GetIndexTop(Cell cell, int size)
{
    if (cell.RowIndex == 0)
        return -1;
    return (cell.RowIndex - 1) * size + cell.ColIndex;
}

private static int GetIndexRight(Cell cell, int size)
{
    if (cell.ColIndex + 1 == size)
        return -1;
    return cell.RowIndex * size + cell.ColIndex + 1;
}

private static int GetIndexLeft(Cell cell, int size)
{
    if (cell.ColIndex == 0)
        return -1;
    return cell.RowIndex * size + cell.ColIndex - 1;
}

private static int GetIndexBottom(Cell cell, int size)
{
    if (cell.RowIndex + 1 == size)
        return -1;
    return (cell.RowIndex + 1) * size + cell.ColIndex;
}
```

**SetIsSink**

```
private static void SetIsSink(Cell[] cells)
{
    foreach (var cell in cells)
        cell.IsSink = (cell.Left == null || cell.Left.Value > cell.Value) &&
                        (cell.Right == null || cell.Right.Value > cell.Value) &&
                        (cell.Top == null || cell.Top.Value > cell.Value) &&
                        (cell.Bottom == null || cell.Bottom.Value > cell.Value);
}
```

**SetNext**

```
private static void SetNext(Cell[] cells)
{
    foreach (var cell in cells.Where(c => !c.IsSink))
        cell.Next = GetNext(cell);
}

private static Cell GetNext(Cell cell)
{
    var cells = new[] {cell.Left, cell.Right, cell.Top, cell.Bottom};
    return cells.Where(c => c != null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Value)
        .First();
}
```

**GetBasins**

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetBasins(Cell[] cells)
{
    var visited = new HashSet<Cell>();
    var basin = cells.Where(c => c.IsSink).ToDictionary(c => c, c => 1);

    foreach (var cell in cells.Where(c => !c.IsSink))
    {
        var current = cell;
        int count = 0;
        while (!current.IsSink)
        {
            if (visited.Add(current)) count++;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        basin[current] += count;
    }

    return basin.Values.OrderByDescending(v => v);
}
```

Comment: why the fancy `yield return` in CreateCells when the only caller's first action is to do a ToArray() on it. Just make CreateCells make an array

Comment: `yield` has been introduced with C# 2.0 (2005)... so it's not fancy but a well-established language element ;). In general I prefer yield compared to introducing a local variable because it simplifies the code. However, the usage in method `CreateCells` is close to the edge...

Comment: @pm100 I don't think it's fancy but rather a good habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious changes are to put most of those static methods into the `Cell` class.

If you thought little bit more carefully you could Tell that `IsSink` and `Next` could be calculated properties, removing the need for the methods `GetNext`, `SetNext` and `SetIsSink`.

```
public Cell Next {
    get
    {
        var cells = new[] { Left, Right, Top, Bottom };
        return cells.Where(c => c != null)
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Value)
                    .First();
    } 
}

public bool IsSink { 
    get {
        return (Left == null || Left.Value > Value) &&
                (Right == null || Right.Value > Value) &&
                (Top == null || Top.Value > Value) &&
                (Bottom == null || Bottom.Value > Value);
    } 
}
```

The same goes for `ConnectCell` and all help methods used there.

```
private void ConnectCell(Cell[,] cells)
{
    Left = ColIndex > 0 ? cells[RowIndex, ColIndex - 1] : null;
    Right = ColIndex < cells.GetLength(1) -1 ? cells[RowIndex, ColIndex - 1] : null;
    Top = RowIndex > 0 ? cells[RowIndex - 1, ColIndex] : null;
    Bottom = RowIndex < cells.GetLength(0) -1 ? cells[RowIndex + 1, ColIndex] : null;
}
```

You don't need to create explicit backfields for the properties `RowIndex`, `ColIndex` and `Value`. Instead create private setters. Example for `Value`

```
public int Value{ get; private set; }
```

It's also worth mentioning that the prefix `my` is not adding any information to the name. In C# it's common the use of `_` as a field prefix instead.

If you are willing to use jagged arrays, you can change `ReadData` to use more `Linq`.

```
private static int[][] ReadData()
{
    var size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var result = new int[size][];
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        var rowData = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToArray()
            .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
            .ToArray();
        result[row] = rowData;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `ToArray` after `Split` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great review! Incredible that I didn't see that lots of the functions actually belong to the cell XD... However, I think I would prefere readonly backfields over private setters because it increases the part of immutable state.